# What is the best practice to create invite code?

Tags: invite

I'm going to generate some invite code. I know a simple method: do n-times loop to get a n-length random string. But it seems that when i want to check the code, it will cost more to find if a code is in data table using a string.

So, what is the best practice to create invite code?

Answer (score 0):

(Old question, but pertinent to some code I'm writing just now...)

Use a GUID, and put an index on the column in the table.  No problem with that.